# Does algebraic isomorphism of unitary irreps of a locally compact group imply unitary isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $X_1,X_2$ unitary irreps of $G$. Assume that there is a $G$-module isomorphism $\phi:X_1\to X_2$ (not necessarily continuous). Does this imply that $X_1\cong X_2$ as unitary representations of $G$?

In the case where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are finite dimensional, this is true because all linear maps between finite dimensional Hilbert spaces are continuous. If $G$ is compact, irreps are finite dimensional by the Peter-Weyl theorem.

Comment: Do you know a counterexample without the irreducibility assumption?

Comment: The worry was that different norms could be put on a large direct sum of irreducible representations. Taking $G=\{e\}$ and representing on Banach spaces instead of Hilbert spaces, $\ell^2$ and $\ell^3$ are algebraically isomorphic, because they are both isomorphic to $\oplus_{|\mathbb {R}|} \mathbb C$. However, I don't know a counterexample in the case I actually asked about.